# Atom IDE Type Contract in Functions Issue

Tags: python, atom-editor

I am new to Atom and was curious why this works in IDLE but not in Atom.
Say I write a bubble sorting algorithm:

```
from typing import List

def bubble_sort(L):
    end = len(L) - 1
    while end != 0:
        for i in range(end):
            if L[i] > L[i + 1]:
                L[i], L[i + 1] = L[i + 1], L[i]
        end = end - 1
```

When I run this in Atom using atom-script it returns:

```
Python - sorts.py.1
[Finished in 0.004s]
```

However, when I write the type contracts in Atom (like what was given below) I'm not able to run the code:

```
from typing import List

def bubble_sort(L: List[int]) -> None:
    end = len(L) - 1
    while end != 0:
        for i in range(end):
            if L[i] > L[i + 1]:
                L[i], L[i + 1] = L[i + 1], L[i]
    end = end - 1
```

When I run this code in Atom using atom-script it outputs:

```
File "/var/folders/7j/13tg190n4pz0vd13874pwg4w0000gn/T/atom_script_tempfiles/628ff580-0c9a- 11ea-a50c-89cd531fad32", line 1
def bubble_sort(L: List[int]):
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
[Finished in 0.05s]
```

I am confused about why this is going on in Atom since I often use type contracts to make code more readable and understandable, and continually deleting the type contracts from the code to run it is rather tedious. Is this a recurring problem for other people or is there another way in which I can include type contracts such that the code runs properly?

Comment: What version of Python is being used when you run the script in Atom? Looks like it might be an older version which doesn’t support type annotations.

Comment: I am using Python 3 would you suggest that I redownload either Python or Atom?

Comment: Atom itself is unlikely to be at fault here, maybe just the interpreter settings. Are you using virtual environments or similar?

Comment: Yes I was just looking into that I have anaconda installed

Comment: Great, I use conda, so that might make things easier here.